# Bootstrap residual resampling in R

Tags: bootstrap, residuals, finance, resampling

Since I am quite new to this topic I have a question regarding bootstrap techniques in R.
I should generate a 10,000 bootstrapped time series by drawing with replacement from the residuals.

This bootstrap should procedure not only preserves the autocorrelation structure of the predictor variable, thereby being valid under the Stambaugh (1999) specification, but also preserves the cross-correlation structure of the two residuals.

The data generating process is assumed to be
$$y_{t+1}=α + u_1{t+1} \\
x_{t+1}=μ + ρ * x_t+u_2t+1$$

In addition, the bootstrap for calculating power assumes the data generating process is
$$
y_t+1 = α+ β  * x_t + u_1t+1 \\
x_t+1 = μ + ρ *x_t + u_2t+1
$$
where both beta and rho are estimated by OLS using the full sample of obersvations, with the residuals stored for sampling.
This follows the bootstrap from Goyal and Welch (2008).

Does anyone have a process in mind for how this can be done?
I know how to compute a "normal" bootstrap but don't know how to adapt it to that given format.

Comment: Please use LaTeX to type equations and make them easier to read, esp. since yours have double indexing. Here are some [resources](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1605/237901).

Comment: Thank you, just edited it.